# Serve any pre-built static site using Hugo server command?

Tags: hugo, liveserver

Is it possible to serve a static site, not necessary a hugo one, using `hugo server` command?

```bash
 cd /path/to/some/static_site
 hugo server [option for watching and serving site(NO BUILDING)]
```

The idea is to use Hugo as a live server during development
even for none Hugo sites since it does the job well. Was hoping
to avoid pulling in additional build dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the command `hugo server`, you can just use the command `hugo` (without any option), and Hugo will render all the content to the `/public` directory. Then, configure your hosting so that your website points to this directory and you will have a static site.

You can alos use `hugo --minify` if you want to minify your content in the `/public` directory.